# Android crashing at getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I decided to switch from multiple activities to one activity which switches between fragments however the application now crashes.

Here is the activity I am adding the fragment to

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

    fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();

}
```

Here is the fragment its an observer and has functionality but to save space ill just show the creation

```
public class MyFragment  extends SherlockFragment implements Observer{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    }
```

Heres my_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

... HAS SOME TEXT VIEWS HERE!
</RelativeLayout>
```

The crash I get is

```
02-15 16:17:41.079: E/AndroidRuntime(18668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 16:17:41.079: E/AndroidRuntime(18668): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No view found for id 0x7f040036 for fragment MyFragmentt{41a05910 #0 id=0x7f040036}
```

Can anyone help me out here? I can't really figure out what is causing this. I know if I comment out getSupportFragmentManager() in main activity  (the top code block in this post) it will run just not draw anything in my fragment.

**UPDATE**

The frame_container which I'm not sure where to place

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Do you have declared `FrameLayout` with that id `R.id.fragment_container` ?

Comment: I have this but I'm not sure if I have it in the right place should it be its own xml fle or should it be in my_fragment.xml or in my activity_main.xml? First time using fragments so I could have made a stupid mistake
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: To make it easier to read I added the frame container to the initial question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way you can use `Fragments` in your applications are two.
First way is if you declare the Fragment in your xml file like this :

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The second way is if you add / replace your Fragments dynamically to your container which in the most examples is `FrameLayout`. Here is how you can do that :

In your main `FragmentActivity` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myFragmentContainer);
}
```

and in your xml `myFragmentContainer.xml` is where you place your `fragment_container` and it looks like :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and you are adding and replacing your `Fragments` like this :

```
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
        // if there are any extras
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
```

and for the next Fragment which you want to show just do :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment).commit();
```